# NSBrowser fills NSPasteboard but won't drop

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard, nsbrowser

I have an NSBroswer with a series of entries that look up a text blob. If the blob exists then
`- (BOOL)browser:canDragRowsWithIndexes:inColumn:withEvent:` returns YES.

This invokes
`- (BOOL)browser:writeRowsWithIndexes:inColumn:toPasteboard:`

In here I do the following:

```
NSUInteger changeCount;
BOOL retBOOL = YES;

changeCount = [pasteboard clearContents];
changeCount = [pasteboard declareTypes:@[NSPasteboardTypeString, NSPasteboardTypeHTML]
                                 owner:self];
didSet = [pasteboard setString:self.currentHTMLCode
                       forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
retBOOL = retBOOL & didSet;
didSet = [pasteboard setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<pre>%@</pre>", self.currentHTMLCode]
                       forType:NSPasteboardTypeHTML];
retBOOL = retBOOL & didSet;
```

Now the data analysis of the pasteboard coming out (with retBOOL: Yes) is:

```
pasteboard: : <NSPasteboard: 0x101931870>
     name: : Apple CFPasteboard drag
     change count: : 77
     types: : (
    "public.utf8-plain-text",
    NSStringPboardType,
    "public.html",
    "Apple HTML pasteboard type"
)
     items: : (
    "<NSPasteboardItem: 0x1005a5cb0>"
)
         PBItem: : <NSPasteboardItem: 0x1005a5cb0>
             PBType: : public.utf8-plain-text
                 String for type [public.utf8-plain-text] = 89958 characters
             PBType: : public.html
                 String for type [public.html] = 89969 characters
retValue: YES
```

So my problem is that when I drag this to SimpleText or BBEdit, nothing drops. I don't see a highlight of the target document. (Note: I also have a drag image routine, and I see the drag image)

Any ideas why I seem to be populating the pasteboard but it refuses to drop in the other app?

Comment: Does your browser invoke `registerForDraggedTypes` for those types?

Comment: No, but then again, I don't want to drag to (drop on) the browser, I want to drag from the browser to (drop on) another app.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. BTW I downloaded the example project SimpleBrowser, added `[_browser setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationAll forLocal:NO];` in awakeFromNib and implemented almost part of your code and it works with TextEdit, Safari & Word

Comment: Here's the [source code](http://pastebin.com/8kYwiKpp)

Comment: This does remedy the issue. Please enter this as an answer so you can pull the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the example project SimpleBrowser by Apple, added

`[_browser setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationAll forLocal:NO];`

in awakeFromNib and implemented almost part of your code and it works with TextEdit, Safari & Word.
Here's the sample [code](http://pastebin.com/8kYwiKpp)